# javascript If statement not recognizing null value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created and if {} else {} but for some reason it's not recognizing the null value in the if {} statement so it's not executing that code. Instead its doing the opposite and executing the else {} code. Am I not using null correctly?

```
function CalculateItem2() 
{

    var item1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_step1amount").getValue();
    if (item1 == null) {
        item1 = 0;
    }

    var item2 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_step2amount").getValue();
    if (item2 == null) {
        item2 = 0;
    }

    if(new_steponecontractrecieved.value!=null)
    {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalamountcollected").setValue(item2);
    } 
    else
    {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalamountcollected").setValue(item1+item2);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you positive the expected value is ```null```? Beware that ```""``` is different than ```null```.

Comment: You should use the `===` operator to check both the value and the type.

Comment: @RafaelQuintanilha I'm trying to check to see if the named field has a populated value.

Comment: Then `if (item1 == '')` as Raphael pointed out is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic javascript check like

```
if(nameOfVariable) //Returns false if variable has null or blank or undefined as value
{

} 
else
{

}
```

Cheers from [CheezyCode](http://www.cheezycode.com)